# System.ComponentModel Attribute for Example Data

Tags: c#, attributes, custom-attributes

I would like to know if there is a suitable attribute in System.ComponentModel which can be used for example data.

if a property is decorated with a description, default and example for the property

```
[Category("Profile")]
[DefaultValue(string, "profile.address@domain.com")]
[Description("The e-mail address for the user profile")]
[Example("ted.smith@example.com")]        // This attribute doesn't exist
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: There is no such attribute, but you can create your own.

Comment: Thanks dymanoid, I would prefer not to create a custom attribute. I have multiple domain models which are segregated and having cross dependencies isn't ideal.